# Looking for a way to write fixed width text in table layout that preserves other SO formatting

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, formatting

Is there a way, possibly a tag, to change the font to fixed-width,
while still preserving other SO formating?

This is my text snippet

```
`code`   Description  `result1`
`longer` ShortText    `result2`
`other`  **BoldText**     `result3`
```

Now what I want to achieve is something like this

`code`        Description   `result1`
`longer`     ShortText     `result2`
`other`       **BoldText**     `result3`

If that seems like an XY problem, the Y question might sound *Can I do tabs or table layouts?*

---

What I am looking for is something like this

```
<fixed-width>
...
</fixed-width>
```

or

```
<!-- font-family: monospace -->
<div>
...
</div>
```

or

```
`code`<xyz>   Description  </xyz>`result1`
```

if it is preffered to avoid intersecting the code blocks.

Comment: If it's not in Markdown, I don't see it happening. And while not completely against the table idea, I think it would be generously abused and a pain to edit out. Having formatting inside code-blocks is logically a no-go...

Comment: @yivi Actually I am not looking for formatting _inside_ code blocks.

Comment: "fixed width text" == code blocks.

Comment: @yivi code blocks are actually _The Gray Blocks_ with pre-formatted fixed-width font that ignores other Markdown. I am looking for a _tag_ or a _comment-like_ annotation (as with lang) that only changes the font without other visual changes to any text (including other Markdown) in it.

Comment: SO uses Markdown. If it's not the [markdown spec](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), I don't see the site extending markdown for something like this, nor I see the utility for it.

Comment: If you really need a table, use a code block? If you really need pretty, formatted prose... use a list, not a table, because formatted text doesn't go nicely in a table?

Comment: Related: [Is there Markdown to create tables?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566) (also status-declined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The site only supports Markdown and a [**very limited subset of HTML**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites). That limited subset does not include tables.

At best you can use `<pre>`, which formats everything as fixed-width font on grey background, just like code blocks would. In such a block you can then use further HTML to produce additional effects, like bolding and italics:

```
<pre>
code        Description   result1
longer      <em>ShortText</em>     result2
other       <strong>BoldText</strong>      result3
</pre>
```

which renders as:

```
code        Description   result1
longer      ShortText     result2
other       BoldText      result3
```

There are no proportional font options, like tables. This is not going to change. As the central FAQ on HTML (linked above) states:

> We do not (and will not) allow `<table>` tags. Sorry. This is intentional and by design. If you need a quick and dirty "table", use `<pre>` and ASCII layout.

Comment: The gray box is sad, but`<pre>` with html is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's been mentioned many places elsewhere at this point, but [tables are now available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) on Stack Overflow and across the Stack Exchange network of sites. See that link for the full slew of details.

What you initially wanted is now somewhat more achievable using this new table syntax, albeit with some limitations. Headers (even if empty) are required on all tables, and the table will always be full-width; using `<pre>` may still be your best bet if these are deal breakers.

The following Markdown:

```md
|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `code` | Description | `result1` |
| `longer` | ShortText | `result2` |
| `other` | **BoldText** | `result3` |
```

Produces this table:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `code` | Description | `result1` |
| `longer` | ShortText | `result2` |
| `other` | **BoldText** | `result3` |

You can even set the alignment per-column if that suits your usage better:

```md
|  |  |  |
|:--- |:---:| ---:|
| `code` | Description | `result1` |
```

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `code` | Description | `result1` |

Note that even with the adoption of this Markdown table syntax, HTML `<table>`'s are still unsupported.